# Precision MySql in division

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
mysql> SELECT CAST(1 / 3 AS DECIMAL(21,20));
+-------------------------------+
| CAST(1 / 3 AS DECIMAL(21,20)) |
+-------------------------------+
|        0.33333333300000000000 |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Is it posible to change the output '0.33333333300000000000' to '0.33333333333333333333' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. Cast one of the values instead of the result in the end

```
SELECT CAST(1 as DECIMAL(21,20)) / 3;
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/85b2e2/27)

Comment: Thanks a lot @juergen d